# How to keep TopMost position of a control MFC?

Tags: c++, mfc

I want to keep a control to be top most. But other controls are redrawed to update images in `OnTimer()` method. So they drawed over the first one I want to keep top most. Although I set

```
m_thumbnail->
SetWindowPos(&wndTopMost , 300, 400, 500, 400, SWP_SHOWWINDOW|SWP_NOZORDER);
```

Any ideas to keep it top most all times.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Tell us more about the re-drawing that happens on a timer. Is that done with `InvalidateRect`. Or do you just splat the drawing right onto the window DC?

Answer (score 0):

The `SetWindowPos`-function has a parameter called `hWndInsertAfter`. With this param you control the z-order of the controls. You also have to remove the `SWP_NOZORDER` flag.

Comment: I also remove SWP_NOZORDER flag. But nothing happens